# How do I populate a list of objects with new values

Tags: scala

Apologies: I'm well noob

I have an items class

```
class item(ind:Int,freq:Int,gap:Int){}
```

I have an ordered list of ints

```
val listVar = a.toList
```

where a is an array

I want a list of items called metrics where

ind is the (unique) integer
freq is the number of times that ind appears in list
gap is the minimum gap between ind and the number in the list before it 
so far I have:

```
def metrics = for {
  n <- 0 until 255 
  listVar filter (x == n) count > 0 
}
  yield  new item(n, (listVar filter == n).count,0)
```

It's crap and I know it - any clues?

Comment: I'm not sure why your question got down voted..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, some of it is easy:

```
val freqMap = listVar groupBy identity mapValues (_.size)
```

This gives you `ind` and `freq`. To get `gap` I'd use a fold:

```
val gapMap = listVar.sliding(2).foldLeft(Map[Int, Int]()) { 
  case (map, List(prev, ind)) =>
    map + (ind -> (map.getOrElse(ind, Int.MaxValue) min ind - prev))
}
```

Now you just need to unify them:

```
freqMap.keys.map( k => new item(k, freqMap(k), gapMap.getOrElse(k, 0)) )
```

Comment: `freqMap.keys.map( k => new item(k, freqMap(k), gapMap.getOrElse(k, 0)) )`

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you want to traverse the list only once and in the course for each different Int, you  want to increment a counter (the frequency) as well as keep track of the minimum gap.

You can use a *case* class to store the frequency and the minimum gap, the value stored will be immutable. Note that minGap may not be defined.

```
case class Metric(frequency: Int, minGap: Option[Int])
```

In the general case you can use a `Map[Int, Metric]` to lookup the `Metric` immutable object. Looking for the minimum gap is the harder part. To look for gap, you can use the `sliding(2)` method. It will traverse the list with a sliding window of size two allowing to compare each Int to its previous value so that you can compute the gap.

Finally you need to accumulate and update the information as you traverse the list. This can be done by folding each element of the list into your temporary result until you traverse the whole list and get the complete result.

Putting things together:

```
listVar.sliding(2).foldLeft(
  Map[Int, Metric]().withDefaultValue(Metric(0, None))
) {
  case (map, List(a, b)) =>
    val metric = map(b)
    val newGap = metric.minGap match {
      case None => math.abs(b - a)
      case Some(gap) => math.min(gap, math.abs(b - a))
    }
    val newMetric = Metric(metric.frequency + 1, Some(newGap))
    map + (b -> newMetric)
  case (map, List(a)) => 
    map + (a -> Metric(1, None))
  case (map, _) => 
    map
}
```

Result for listVar: List[Int] = List(2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4)

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Metric] = Map(2 -> Metric(4,Some(0)), 
4 -> Metric(4,Some(0)), 0 -> Metric(1,Some(4)))
```

You can then turn the result into your desired item class using `map.toSeq.map((i, m) => new Item(i, m.frequency, m.minGap.getOrElse(-1)))`.

You can also create directly your Item object in the process, but I thought the code would be harder to read.